# React Leaflet Map simple external - href - button in Nav bar above map that pans-zooms map to a point on Map

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, leaflet, href

This I am sure is easy but cannot find a simple example of it anywhere that works with React Leaflet.
Trying to simply have a button external to the map that pans and zooms the map to that point.
Assuming needs to be more React/Leaflet React specific to ones I have tried.
Fine with adding markers popups etc see example.
Hope someone out there has a small example of how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of Map]

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/remove-zoom-control-from-map-in-react-leaflet-without-hooks-xmxwf). It is very close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you very much for this. Is a good feature to be able to put the zoom controls outside the map. Still hoping for an exact example so I can see how you then use smooth zoom function to go from button to button. Any other examples out there you know of? Seems to be very hard to find one so far.

Comment: Finally found an example for external button for anyone else out there trying to find this exact here is a link to it. And thanks again to Ivan going to use that example as well. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html